# Drop Off Library and Custom workflow not working together

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

We have been using the drop-off Library available in SharePoint Online to move the documents to FinanceDocumentLibrary and HRDocumentLibrary based on the metadata **Type** field. We have configured the Content Organizer Rule and the documents are moving to the destination document library properly.

We have developed a custom SharePoint Designer Approval Workflow which will update the Type (Finance/HR) through workflow. When the Type column is set through Workflow the rule set in the Content Organizer is not working properly, i.e the document is not moving to destination library based on the type set. Instead when the form is saved changed manually the document is moved to proper destination.

Have any one of you faced such an issue earlier.